# Unable to update Event on Public Calendar

Tags: event, calendar

One of the user is getting below error when she is trying to update date field on custom object which in turn updates public calendar event start date.This functionality is in trigger which updates public calendar event whenever there is any change to custom object record.

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00U5000000LL2J2EAL; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, You can not update fields except ReminderDateTime and IsReminderSet on a child event.: [Subject]

Comment: Did you check the access assigned to the user on the calendar?

Comment: @rao user has full access to public calendar

Comment: check to see if the event FLS is configured for the user's profile and see if she has edit access to all the fields being updated (assuming a trigger)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out that there are child events that's getting created when u invite some one on event and child event is just a copy of parent event.
Trigger is trying to update child event and its failing as you cannot edit child event.

So I have added a filter in query to update only parent event (isChild = false) and that's resolving the error.

Here is the [link](http://theblogreaders.com/how-to-identify-the-parent-event-id-from-child-event-in-salesforce/#.VUuhlflViko)  which helped me in solving the mystery.